# PHP generate csv daily using cron job

Tags: php, mysql, cron

I am tasked to generate a CSV. It's easy but I have a trouble on the part that I need to generate it daily.

I use this query on the date part

```
(AD.FINISH_DATE between DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND NOW())
```

The problem here is if I generate a csv today 11/12/2015 and tomorrow at 12Am 11/13/2015 then those file I generate yesterday will be generated on tomorrow's file (11/13/2015).

I got this 3 sample dataset:

```
app         created              finished
137893  2015-11-11 18:36:17 2015-11-11 18:37:25
137896  2015-11-12 08:59:14 2015-11-12 09:01:33
137892  2015-11-11 18:31:15 2015-11-11 18:32:25
137883  2015-11-11 16:43:05 2015-11-11 16:44:41
```

Please help. Thanks

Comment: What is your requirement and can you include a sample dataset?

Comment: I just need to generate a dataset that is within 24 hours range. I got 3 samples here

Comment: Within 24 hours of what? In your sample data, can you demonstrate how what you are doing is not working, in terms of actual vs expected results?

Comment: 24 hours of finished data

Comment: If you can better articulate your issue, you may be able to get a little more help.

Comment: Nah I figure it out used PHP to manipulate the date $today = date('Y-m-d'.' 00:00:01');

$today = date('Y-m-d'.' 00:00:00');

$yesterdayFormula = strtotime ( '-1 day' , strtotime ( $today ) ) ;
$yesterdayFormula = date ( 'Y-m-d' , $yesterdayFormula );
$yesterday = $yesterdayFormula.' 00:00:00';

Answer (score 0):

I used a php script to generate a mysql query then made the csv using this parameter of today and yesterday

```
$today = date('Y-m-d'.' 00:00:00');

$yesterdayFormula = strtotime ( '-1 day' , strtotime ( $today ) ) ;
$yesterdayFormula = date ( 'Y-m-d' , $yesterdayFormula );
$yesterday = $yesterdayFormula.' 00:00:00';
```

Changed the

```
(AD.FINISH_DATE between DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND NOW())
```

changed value:

```
(AD.FINISH_DATE between '$yesterday' and '$today')
```